# Laravel get value from another table based on id

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I want to get department_name from department table
with

```
table department = id, department_name, total_employee
table employee = id, employee_name, id_department, email, telephone, gender, status
```

I tried
model.Employee

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

controllers.EmployeeControllers

```
public function index()
    {
        $data_employee = Employee::with('department')->get();
        return view ('employee.index', compact('data_employee '));
    }
```

with view

```
@forelse ($data_employee as $item)
<tr>
  <td class="text-center">{{ $item->employee_name}}</td>
  <td class="text-center">{{ $item->department->department_name}}</td>
  <td class="text-center">{{ $item->email}}</td>
  <td class="text-center">{{ $item->telephone}}</td>
</tr>
@endforelse
```

But then it said

> Attempt to read property "department_name" on null

What do I do wrong.

Comment: Typo in `return $this->belongsTo(Departemen::class)` , should it be `Department` instead..?

Answer (score 1):

Please replace model.Employee

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'id_department');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to write your relationship properly.

```
public function department()
{
    // You have to provide correct model name here.
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class); 
}
```

Secondly *Eloquent determines the foreign key name by examining the **name of the relationship method** and suffixing the method name with **_id**. So, in your case, Eloquent assumes that the Employee model has a department_id column. But, the foreign key on the Phone model is not department_id , you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method*

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'id_department');
}
```

[Source here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship)